# How to write the junit test for the excelwriter class

Tags: junit

How to write the junit test for the ExcelWriter class? honestly I've been stuck for this all night. thanks. this is for website analysis program. this part of the code is to create excel file that's from the analysis.

```
public class ExcelWriter {
    
    // Create website variable
    Website local_Website;

    // Create a new Excel file
    String local_FileName;

    private static Object headerRow;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private ExcelWriter() {
        // do nothing
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for the ExcelWriter class.
     * @param website The website to be written to the Excel file.
     * @param fileName The name of the Excel file.
     */
    public ExcelWriter(Website local_Website, String local_FileName) {
        this.local_Website = local_Website;
        this.local_FileName = local_FileName;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to create the name of Excel according to design notes.
     * 
     * @return The name of the Excel file.
     */ 
    public String create_Excel_File_Name() {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
        LocalDateTime right_Now = LocalDateTime.now();
        return dtf.format(right_Now) + ".xlsx";
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to write the Excel file.
     * 
     * @return file path and excel file name.
     */
    public String createExcel(){
        
        // create a new workbook file
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    
        // create a new sheet
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Summary");

        // create a new row
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

        // create new cells and header    
            ((Row) headerRow).createCell(0).setCellValue("Page");
            ((Row) headerRow).createCell(1).setCellValue("# Images");
            ((Row) headerRow).createCell(2).setCellValue("# CSS");
            ((Row) headerRow).createCell(3).setCellValue("# Scripts");
            ((Row) headerRow).createCell(4).setCellValue("# Links (Intra-Page)");
            ((Row) headerRow).createCell(5).setCellValue("# Links (Internal)");
            ((Row) headerRow).createCell(6).setCellValue("# Links (External)");
            
        // Initialize the row counter
        int row_Number = 1;
        // Iterate through the website's pages        
        for (Iterator<HTMLDocument> webPage = local_Website.getAllPagesIterator(); webPage.hasNext();) {
            
            row = sheet.createRow(row_Number++);
            HTMLDocument page = webPage.next();           
                    
             //page value 
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(page.getlocalPath().toString());
                    
            //# images value
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(page.getTotalNumberOfLocalImages() + page.getTotalNumberOfExternalImages());
    
            //# CSS value
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(page.getTotalNumberOfLocalStylesheets());
    
            //# Scripts value
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue(page.getTotalNumberOfLocalScripts());
    
            //# Links (Intra-page) value
            row.createCell(4).setCellValue(page.getTotalNumberOfIntrapageLinks());
    
            //# Links (Internal) value
            row.createCell(5).setCellValue(page.getTotalNumberOfInternalLinks());
    
            //# Links (External) value
            row.createCell(6).setCellValue(page.getTotalNumberOfExternalLinks());
                }
                
    }
    
    //create a file path for the Excel file
    String file_Path = local_FileName + createExcel() + ".xlsx";

    //create a file object for the Excel file
    FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
    try {
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file_Path);
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        workbook.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "The program has created the folowing file: " + file_Path + "\n";

    
}
}
```